# Do I need to import class into an external interface file that contains function that get this class object as parameter?

Tags: typescript, module, interface

I write an external interface file which contains  number of functions for the Game class. One of these functions takes a Player object as a parameter. Should I import the Player file into the interface file?

```
interface GameInterface {
    addPlayer(player: Player);
    gamePlayers();
    nextMove(row: number, col: number):boolean;
    validateCell(row: number, col: number): boolean;
    lookForWinningPattern();
    horizontal(): boolean;
    vertical(): boolean;
    diagonalLeftToRight(): boolean;
    diagonalRightToLeft(): boolean;
    printSummary ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't import the whole file. You just need to import the `Player` interface/class from that file. Also, you want to export your interface, since you will be using that in other files:

```
import {Player} from './player'; // Or wherever the player interface/class is located

export interface GameInterface {
    addPlayer(player: Player);
    gamePlayers();
    nextMove(row: number, col: number):boolean;
    validateCell(row: number, col: number): boolean;
    lookForWinningPattern();
    horizontal(): boolean;
    vertical(): boolean;
    diagonalLeftToRight(): boolean;
    diagonalRightToLeft(): boolean;
    printSummary ();
}
```

As long as you use Player only as a type, this will **not bundle** the player. Player will only be used during compilation for type checking.